# Mongoose GeoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm building an api but i'm stuck now cause i can't find a way to make geo searches

Here's the model

```
  var Event = new Schema({
    idactivites : {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },

    nom: String,

    description: String,

    location : {
      type : {
      type: String,
      default: "Point"
       },

    coordinates : {
      type: [Number],
      index: '2d'
      }
    },

    created: {
      type: Date,
      required: false,
    },

    modified: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  });
```

And here's the part of the code that processes my query

```
app.get('/api/geo_events', function(req, res) {


  var latitude = req.query.latitude;
  var longitude = req.query.latitude;
  var radius = req.query.radius/6371 || 5000/6371;

  var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 20;

  if(latitude && longitude)
  {
    var q = EventModelModel.find({'location': {
      $near: [
          longitude,
          latitude
          ],
          $maxDistance: radius
        }
      });
  }

  return  q.exec(function (err, events) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(events);
    }
  });
});
```

Where am I wrong ? 
I did not include here the parts in case of errors, but rest assured there are in my code.

Thanks in advance,
Jeremie.

Comment: Please provide error messages you get and highlight code parts you are curious about.

Comment: Here's the errror

`Internal error(500): error processing query: ns=test1.locationsTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=0.784806 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
GET /api/geo_events/?latitude=2&longitude=47&radius=5000 500 6.931 ms - 24`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combine geoNear query with another query for a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584279/combine-geonear-query-with-another-query-for-a-value)